# MechanicalSoup with Login: Unable to browser.download_link() with given URL & save-path

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, download, mechanicalsoup

Im currently trying to fetch some files from an internal network. I managed to fetch the URLs of some files in the format
`https://example.site/files/testfile.pdf`.
Now I've tried to download this particular file by using the following:

```py
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
for s in site_links ##s = 'https://example.site/file/.../.../file.pdf'
##print(s)
browser.download_link(s, "X:/FolderA/FolderB/test.pdf")
```

But each time PyCharm throws an error at me which I don't understand (I am new to Python).

I've searched around but all I found was Python2 related stuff or downloads without authentication with username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, `s` is a URL; but `browser.download_link` takes a link, i.e. something like `<a href="...">...</a>`.

You can pass `download_link` the link if you have it. If not, MechanicalSoup doesn't have a convenience function for downloading from a URL directly, so you would need to do a little more work. For example, the following (untested) code should do what you want:

```py
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
response = browser.open(url)
with open('file_to_download_to', 'wb') as fid:
    fid.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer & your snippet. I wasn't aware of this and will give it a try later today. I will submit feedback on whether it worked. :)

Comment: I think it works. I now just have to figure out how to name the file as well as the data type correctly. At this moment it overwrites itself again and again. Is it possible to do this automatically or is there something like .substring()?

Comment: i just created a substring by using `partition(str_pattern)` to get the file name + file type.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you! If each file has a unique name on the server, then you could also name your output file with something like `os.path.basename(url)`.

Comment: yeah i thought about how to check this the correct way. I need to check my local folder against the network one. If there is for example a change within a .doc without renaming, I'm actualy unable to fetch this change. I tried it first but this lead to a massive increase in runtime that was just unpracticly - maybe because I did it the wrong way...
Do you know a convenient workaround for this problem?